# What does "set _" in a for loop?

Tags: batch-file

I had a problem that Win7 hangs on shutdown screen for over 30 mins.....
then I found this batch file was the cause, but i dont understand what's the purpose of this.

The shutdown only hangs on after join to domain.
This batch file was in c:\ntfs\bin
After I removed this batch file, no more hangs

Issue fixed but i want to know what does this script mean. I dont know much about batch file
please give me a hint

---

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in (`set _`) do set %%a=
```

---

Comment: Change question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use better:

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set "_"') do set "%%a="
```

This code deletes all environment variables starting with `_` (underscore) in the current `setlocal-endlocal` block. If you use this in a batch file without the `setlocal` command, the varialbles are removed from the current command prompt session.

The use of `usebackq` and `tokens` is not needed in this case, see `help for` for more help on the command prompt.

Comment: does this have anything to do with shutdown process? PC only hangs on shutdown screen when it is in domain....

Comment: In pure Windows I can't imagine such a process. But yes, you can make a program looking at environment variables and shutdown the system, if some (or just one) is removed (virus?). But not Windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

It deletes all variables that start with an underscore (for example `_test` or `_whatever`)